# change only the theme language

Tags: language, translation

My wordpress admin is in french.
and my theme is in arabic.
i have two files mo : arabic and french.

i used this :

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'change_locale' );
function change_locale(){ return 'pt_AR'; }
load_default_textdomain();
load_textdomain('responsive', get_template_directory().'/languages/pt_AR.mo');
```

i have my site web in araic only if i deleted the file french pt_FR.mo
if this file exit, my site web is will be in french not in arabic

how can fixed it ?!

Comment: Is there a reason for using non-standard locales? Can you use 'ar' for Arabic and 'fr_FR' for French? If you can I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: jsute i rename the file arabic with ar.mo and the french and the french file with fr_FR ? and i change the code with this :add_filter( 'locale', 'change_locale' );
function change_locale(){ return 'ar'; }
load_default_textdomain();
load_textdomain('responsive', get_template_directory().'/languages/ar.mo'); ?!

Comment: i have creat the two file translation my theme with poedit in arabic and in french  .... for used in futur if the client needed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rename your `pt_AR.mo` to `ar.mo` and `pt_FR` to `fr_FR.mo`.

In step one install but not activate yet the plugin **Admin in English**. Edit the plugin's php script. Find line with `en_US` string and replace this string with `fr_FR`. Save and activate the plugin. Now your Dashboard will be in French. 
In step two remove first three lines of your code from theme's `functions.php and replace fourth one with`load_theme_textdomain('responsive', get_template_directory().'/languages');`. 
In final step go to`Réglages -> Général` and select **Arabic** as your site's language.
Now you should have your front end in Arabic and back end in French.